# Redirect Search results from google to a specific page

Tags: php, javascript, search, http-referer

HI,

I have a specific requirement, when a user searches in google.com which returns me a list of results and one of the results is my website but it is pointing to a different page.

I need help in 2 places,

1. Client is planing to enhance my website so that what ever link of my website appears in google results should show as cars.com/search.jsp?search=audi. I will be having the logic in my search.jsp or search.php page which navigates the user to an appropriate page.
2. Or will the use the http_referrer stuff in all the pages of my website to redirect to different pages helps me in this case ?

Is this possible to implement, please guide me regarding this.

Thanks
Gopi

Comment: Google doesn't normally like to index search pages - this idea of yours won't work too well.

It's better if you setup some sort of tag cloud system.

Comment: @xil3 If there's a link somewhere to `cars.com/search.jsp?search=audi` and unless you've told Google to ignore the `search` query parameter in Google Webmasters, Google will index that page.

Comment: @Artefacto It's frowned upon by Google, and the Google bot can usually tell the difference between a search page and one that's not. Even if it does get indexed, it wouldn't last long.

Answer (score 1):

> every link of my website appears in google results should show as `cars.com/search.jsp?search=audi`. I will be having the logic in my search.jsp or search.php page which navigates the user to an appropriate page.

Hum? The only way to do this is to have Google index **exactly** one page – that is, `cars.com/search.jsp?search=audi`. You probably don't want that.

> Or will the use the http_referrer stuff in all the pages of my website to redirect to different pages helps me in this case ?

This is a possibility, but beware that if show pages that are significantly different than what Google indexes, you'll be violating their terms and risk yourself to being removed from Google's index.